# Python Coursera Assignement

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python through a course on Courser, and so far having a feeling I am not going to be able to.

I don't want an answer to the assignment, I want someone to push me in the right direction.  Because Im stuck and the online tutors there are not being any help just repeating the obvious that is already stated in the assignment.  The assignment is very simple, but I cant understand what I am missing.

Here is the assignment:
*Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter the numbers from the book for problem 5.1 and Match the desired output as shown.*

Here is my code, i tried using the example codes we where show for getting the minimum and maximum, but the problem is in the examples we had they had lists, here I was told I dont need a list.  But everytime the value of num changes with ever new input, how can i get the program to choose from certain numbers if they are not storing...or do you think i can enter lists in the raw_input?

```
while True:
    inpt = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inpt == "done" : break

    try:
        num = int(inpt)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
    continue

largest = None
if largest is None:
    largest = num
elif num > largest:
    largest = num

smallest = None 
if smallest is None:
    smallest = num
elif num < smallest:
    smallest = num

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

The numbers from the book are 4, 5, 7 and a word

**Thank you everyone for your support,** I understand what I have to do, not sure if I understand how I will get there, but Im going to sit and keep trying. Meanwhile I am getting issues with indentation 
let's say I rewrote the code like this and want to add an if statement into the while loop

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    inpt = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inpt == "done" : break

    try:
        num = int(inpt)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
    continue
```

should the if statement start with the same indent as the continue and then the inside of the if indented again??  Because Im getting errors when I do that

Comment: Of course you need to store the numbers somehow, what you are not doing. Just read them in and insert them into a list. What do you think is happening in your min-max calculation in it's current form? Where is the information of the past? **Alternatively:** just use two variables, one for min, one for max, and update these for each input (= lowest observed number until now, highest...)! These updates are within the while-loop!

Comment: Have faith, young wizard. All formidable sourcerers once started by getting their incantations wrong and their cauldrons exploding. Do not give up on magic altogether on account of a few dud spells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I think, and the thing that was killing my code was the continue statement if I am not wrong

here is what i got, and please leave comments if I got it wrong

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    inpt = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if inpt == "done" : break

    try:
        num = int(inpt)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"

    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num

    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 largest = None
    smallest = None
    while True:
        inp = input("Enter a number: ")
        if inp == "done" : break
        try:
            num = float(inp)
        except:
            print ("Invalid input")
            continue
        if smallest is None:
            smallest=num
        if num > largest :
            largest=num
        elif num < smallest :
            smallest=num
    
    def done(largest,smallest):
       print("Maximum is", int(largest))
       print("Minimum is", int(smallest))
    
    
    done(largest,smallest)

this will surly work.
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, while this may answer the question, it is better to give explanations and not only code for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with your current implementation, but there is some issues in the order of your operations, and where the operations are taking place. Trace through your program step by step, and try to see why your `None` assignment may be causing some issues, among other small things.

Answer (score 1):

You are being asked to keep a running max and running min, the same way you could keep a running total. You just update the running <whatever> inside the loop, then discard the user's most recent input. In the case of running total, the code would look like `tot = tot + newinput` and you could then discard `newinput` (or, more likely, reuse it) without recording it in a list or any other data structure.

Not every problem permits a "running" solution. For instance, if you wanted to give the user an undo feature, letting them back out some of the numbers they entered earlier, you would have to keep an exact history of all the numbers. But here, you can get by without keeping that data.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the largest and smallest numbers inside the loop. First check if its a number - if yes, carry on and see if it is bigger than your current `largest` variable value (start with 0). If yes, replace it. See, if its smaller than your `smallest` value (start with the first number that comes in, if you start with 0 or just a random number, you might not get lower that that. If you start with the first number, then it'll definitely be the smallest (after all the loops)), etc, etc. All of that should be done inside the loop and after the loop should be just the printing. And yes, you don't need to use lists.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a hint here, every time your `while` loop takes in a input, it sets the values of `largest` and `smallest` to `None`. Where should you initialize them?

Answer (score 0):

I sense that your confusion partly stems from how the user is expected to give the input. One could interpret the instructions in two ways.

1. The user writes `4 5 7 randomword [ENTER]`
2. The user writes `4 [ENTER] 5 [ENTER] 7 [ENTER] randomword [ENTER]`

If it was the first variant, then you might be expected to process the whole thing as a list and determine its parts

However, the fact that they told you "you will not need lists for this exercise" implies that they expect the second scenario. Which means you should design your `while` loop such that at each iteration it expects to receive a single input from the user, and do something with it (i.e. check if it's bigger / smaller than the last). Whereas the loop you have now, will simply always keep the last input entered, until "done" is encountered.

Once you're out of the `while` loop, all you need to do is present the variables that you've so carefully collected and kept updating inside the loop, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    inp = input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done" : break
    try:
        num = float(inp)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue
    if smallest is None:
        smallest=num
    if num > largest :
        largest=num
    elif num < smallest :
        smallest=num

def done(largest,smallest):
   print("Maximum is", int(largest))
   print("Minimum is", int(smallest))


done(largest,smallest)
```

Comment: It would be good to have a couple comments why this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
maximum = -1
minimum = None
while True:
    num = input('Enter the num: ')
    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        num1 = int(num)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
    if minimum is None:
        minimum = num1
    if num1 > maximum:
        maximum = num1
    elif num1 < minimum:
        minimum = num1

print('Maximum is', maximum)
print('Minimum is', minimum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" :
        break
    try:
        n=int(num)
    
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
        
    if largest is None:
        largest=n
    if n > largest:
        largest=n
    if smallest is None:
        smallest=n
    elif n < smallest:
        smallest =n

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is" , smallest)
```